# PPC64 subroutine call from inline assembly

Tags: powerpc

I am trying to write a simple function using inline assembly in C for powerpc64, my function calls another function and I have a couple of questions related to that.

1) How do I save the LR register before branching using 'bl ' to the subroutine?

Specifically, for this code:

```
void func(void *arg1, void *arg2)
{
   void *result;
   __asm__ volatile (
   ...
   ...
   "bl <address>\n"        //Call to subroutine
   "nop\n"
   ...
   : [result]"=r"(result)
   : [arg1]"r"(arg1),
     [arg2]"r"(arg2)
   );
   return result;
}
```

The compiler generates the prologue code for this without the "mflr 0;std 0, 16(1)" instructions to save LR since it does not know that a subroutine is being called in my assembly code. Do I include these instructions in my assembly code? If so, how do I know the stack size created by the compiler prologue code to get to the LR save area of the function calling 'func'? (from powerpc assembly tutorials on developerworks the LR registers needs to be saved in the 'calling' function's stack frame)

2) I believe I will need to save arg1 and arg2 before calling the subroutine, which is the right place to temp store these parameters before making a subroutine call - the parameter save area or non-volatile registers? I just want to know the right way this is done in production quality ppc64 code

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest you to write this function directly in assembly. I have to say I have never seen a call to subroutine from an asm inline block (which use is already complex without that). I am not sure the approach you chose is compatible with "production quality code". I don't blame the experiment at all (I also spent time to understand inline asm) but I think it is complicated: LR and other registers have to be saved ... but that means to create the prologue / epilogue of the func function inside the inline asm block! By the way, what is the purpose of this function?

Comment: Thanks amigadev! The function I'm trying to write does some stack manipulation, I want to call a subroutine from this function that saves the content of the stack in the heap. I considered writing the code directly in assembly but I am doing this as part of a project and the same function for other platforms (x86 etc) have a simple inline function and doing the assembly file for ppc would need some special Makefile changes. I am new to writing ppc assembly so it's kind of surprising that doing such a simple thing as calling a subroutine is so hard to do from inline assembly

Comment: The complexity relies on inline assembly, not PPC assembly ;-) mpe's answer gives more accurate facts about what to do. And he also says that with inline assembly, it is difficult to be pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to do this properly. Inline asm is not designed for calling functions.

You can't reliably know the size of the stack frame the compiler has generated, in fact the entire function could be inlined, or as you observed the compiler might not generate a stack frame at all.

But you don't **have** to store LR in the caller stack frame, it's best if you do, but it's not 100% required. So just put it in a non-volatile, mark that register as clobbered, and restore it on the way back.

You shouldn't need to save arg1 and arg2, but what you must do is mark all the volatile registers as clobbered. Then the compiler will save anything that is in volatile registers (like arg1 and arg2) before it calls your asm. Also remember that some CR fields might be clobbered. I'd also add 'memory' to the clobbers so that GCC is pessimistic about optimising across the asm.

If you do all that it **might** work, unless I'm forgetting something :)